# In Excel how to get original row index after sort

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting

I work on writing the excel Add-In using Excel Interop. I want to get original row index after using sort in Excel. For example:

Original Text in Excel:

```
       A        B      
    1  Name     Country
    2  Douglas  CA
    3  Alice    US
```

After Sort:

```
       A        B      
    1  Name     Country
    2  Alice    US
    3  Douglas  CA
```

Orginal named "Douglas" row index is 2. After sorting row index is 3.
How to get original row index(the row index is 2) after sorting?

Comment: after you've done the sorting is too late. You should either add an index or store the value *before* sorting

Comment: @JMax - Bang on. You must have been tempted to post that as an answer. If not you should be.

Comment: @brettdj: thanks. As suggested, I've added this comment as an answer. I've slightly elaborated it though if my comment wasn't clear enough for the OP :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot find **back** the *original index* **after** you've done the sorting because it is too late. Excel doesn't store the history.

Some tips to solve this:

- **add an index** brefore sorting (in a new column for instance)
- **store the value** before sorting (in your VBA, in a multidimensional array for instance)

Comment: Thanks. I will test these ways. It is uncomfortable that making Add-In with Excel.